# Replace Double Quotes comma separator within Brackets [] using sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the data given below with other lines of data in a huge file to be more specific this is a .json file, I have stripped the whole file except for this one catch.

**Data:**

- ,"value":["ABC-DE","XYZ-MN"]
- ,"value":["MNO-RS"],"sub_id":01
- "value":"[\"NEW-XYZ\"]","
- ,"value":["ABC-DE","XYZ-MN","MNO-BE","FRS-ND"]

I want the data to look like this

- ,"value":["ABC-DE,XYZ-MN"]-Changed
- ,"value":["MNO-RS"],"sub_id":01-Unchanged
- "value":"[\"NEW-XYZ\"]","-Unchnaged
- ,"value":["ABC-DE,XYZ-MN,MNO-BE,FRS-ND"]-Changed

So far I have this piece of code however it seems to be replacing the whole files "," with , and not the ones just within []

```
sed 's/\(\[\|\","\|\]\)/\,/g' testfile_1.txt >testfile_2.txt
```

Any help would be great

**Note: Edited fourth condition

Cheers.

Comment: The quantifiers ?, +, {n}, {n,m} and {n,}  repeat the preceding token zero or once, once or more, n times, between n and m times, and n or more times,

Comment: sed defaults to BRE: The default behaviour of sed is to support Basic Regular Expressions (BRE). To use extended features  set the -r (Linux) or -E (BSD) flag to use ERE.

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me is you could try multiple sed passes.  Like one to remove all quotes then another sed pass to add them back where needed?  (daisychaining sed's in other words). I don't know if that's more effective or not, anyway, thanks again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's tougher without the non-greedy matching perl regex offers, but this seems to do it.

```
sed -e 's/\([^\[]*\"[A-Z\-]*\)\",\"\(.*\)/\1,\2/'
```

Comment: Thank you @clearlight but I found a way to do it the traditional way ;)

Comment: This is a traditional POSIX regex, not perl. What was your solution? Can you update your question? Also if my answer is good, please click √ check mark next to it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I mean can you add your answer so we can see another way of solving it? Or by traditional do you mean non-regex?

Comment: Both our answers seem to do the trick, but here is a scenario that fails

My Code: sed -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)","/\1,/' testfile_1.txt >testfile_2.txt

Comment: Thanks Avin! Good work. Glad you stuck with it. Satisfying.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Your solution looks cleaner. In fact, I have to figure out how it works now :-)

Comment: Thanks mate, see the fourth data point I have added to the question, it seems to fail to remove " in both our cases, wonder how we can manage to replace "," with , irrespective to the number of occurrence within []

Comment: Do you *need* to use sed/POSIX re's? They're such a hassle. It's so much easier with non-greedy operators.  I use regex's in BBEdit (on Mac), all the time, very powerul and don't need to escape nearly as many characters. And it handles repeats and conditionals. Some of that can be done with POSIX but I have to re-learn it all every time.

Comment: The quantifiers ?, +, {n}, {n,m} and {n,} repeat the preceding token zero or once, once or more, n times, between n and m times, and n or more times, respectively. Alternation is supported through the usual vertical bar |. Unadorned parentheses create a group, e.g. (abc){2} matches abcabc. The POSIX standard does not define backreferences. Some implementations do support \1 through \9, but these are not part of the standard for ERE. ERE is an extension of the old UNIX grep, not of POSIX BRE.

Comment: POSIX standard is from 1986 - ancient! RE's have come a long ways since then.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions @clearlight

Here is my solution to the problem with multiple occurrences;

```
sed -e ': a' -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)","/\1,/' -e 't a' testfile_1.txt >testfile_2.txt
```

Using label 'a' till end of label 'a'

pseudocode:

```
while (not end of line){ replace "," with ' }
```